# weights = 'noisy-student' ValueError: The `weights` argument should be either `None`, `imagenet`, or the path to the weights file to be loaded

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, valueerror, efficientnet

I am using Google Colab and I want to use the weights of EfficientNet Noisy Student. https://www.kaggle.com/c/bengaliai-cv19/discussion/132894

First, I installed the package via:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/qubvel/efficientnet
```

Then I tried the code found on the site mentioned above:

```
import efficientnet.keras as eff
model = eff.EfficientNetB0(weights='noisy-student')
```

And got this Value error:

```
ValueError: The `weights` argument should be either `None` (random initialization), `imagenet` (pre-training on ImageNet), or the path to the weights file to be loaded.
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could download the weights from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/ipythonx/efficientnet-keras-noisystudent-weights-b0b7).
And load it manually like this:

```
path_to_weights = "/..your..path../efficientnet-b5_noisy-student_notop.h5"
model = EfficientNetB5(include_top=False)
model.load_weights(path_to_weights, by_name=True)
```